# When embedding cover art as a tag to audio files, is the same image copied to each file?

Tags: audio, metadata, tags

Modern audio formats supporting saving album cover art as metadata. Is the same image always copied to all tracks, increasing overall file size? The same picture would be multiplied by dozens and even over a hundred times with some records.

If it is, using high-quality cover art isn't truly feasible especially with lossy audio formats.

Comment: It's pretty easy to test it yourself, you've even described the test procedure in your question: _"Is the same image always copied to all tracks, increasing overall file size?"_

Comment: @gronostaj: I don't know how many music metadata containers there are and I'm not familiar with music "tagging" software. I'd also need all related audio formats and versions. I consider this question as a worthwhile contribution.

Comment: Not sure I understand your specific question, or – for that matter – the particular context or problem you're trying to solve. Why would you need a list of audio formats and versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've observed, album art metadata according is embedded in each file – after all, the files should be portable and not be dependent on any other file. What if you want to just share one file with someone? You'd have to copy the metadata along with it.

Hence, enabling this information to be shared across files (e.g., within an album of multiple tracks that have the same cover art) is not practical.

The relevant specifications would be:

- MP3s: [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_embedded_image_extension) (in its various versions) can hold various image types and image semantics (e.g. front vs. back cover).
- MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 12): the artwork is stored in the `covr` atom and can be JPEG or PNG.

Both ID3 and the `covr` atom are non-standard but *de-facto* standard extensions.

> If it is, using high-quality cover art isn't truly feasible especially with lossy audio formats.

That's not quite correct. It's absolutely feasible; your only limit would be file size, but if you're going for lossy audio, you're likely dealing with several MB per file, and so a JPG-compressed image at high quality will perhaps add another 500 kB on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases album art is embedded in the file itself, causing a lot of duplication as you observed.

However, there are ways of embedding image metadata inside a music file which is a pointer to another file, removing the duplication.

For example, [for ID3 you specify the image MIME type as `-->` and use an absolute URL to the image for the *Picture data* field](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Attached_picture).

[You can do something similar for FLAC.](https://xiph.org/flac/format.html#metadata_block_picture)

Whether the music player you use supports this is another matter. Furthermore not all containers/tagging formats may support it. And, of course, the URL always has to be accessible.