# How does one add cover art to an ID3 tag in the format of a file link?

Tags: mp3, id3

According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/1351254) answer, it's possible according to the ID3 spec (Wayback required to view [the link in that question](https://web.archive.org/web/20210224164038/https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Attached_picture)) to add cover art (for an MP3 file, I assume) as a link to an image file, as opposed to embedding the cover art in the file, allowing for a significant reduction of duplicated data in the case of albums with many files sharing the same cover art.

Apparently, this is done by setting the MIME type to `-->` and providing a 'complete URL' to the image file in place of the image data. However, short of writing a program to interface with the file and write the data to the ID3 tag directly, I can't find any method for *how* to actually do this—software; terminal commands; or so on.

It sounds like 'complete URL' refers to an absolute file path (`C:\Users\...\cover_art.jpg`), as opposed to a relative one. If so, I can see this being a pretty useless feature, especially regarding portability between systems, but it would still be good to know *how* to do this, in case it ends up being useful.